# What starts this docker process on my laptop?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, jenkins

Every time I boot up my Lubuntu 16.04 laptop I can see I have a running docker container:

```
$ ps -ef | grep docker
root      1724     1  3 21:17 ?        00:01:30 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
root      1774  1724  0 21:17 ?        00:00:04 docker-containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd --shim docker-containerd-shim --runtime docker-runc
root      4750  1774  0 21:17 ?        00:00:00 docker-containerd-shim 72541a4648b890132985daf2357d1130b8b5208cf12ede607b93ab2987629719 /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/72541a4648b890132985daf2357d1130b8b5208cf12ede607b93ab2987629719 docker-runc
stephane 10755  1793  0 22:07 pts/0    00:00:00 grep docker
```

It serves a Jenkins application on the port 80 and requesting `localhost/` in the browser redirects to `http://localhost/login?from=%2F` and shows a Jenkins warning page:

```
Unlock Jenkins
To ensure Jenkins is securely set up by the administrator, a password has been written to the log (not sure where to find it?) and this file on the server:
```

A wget request shows:

```
$ wget localhost/
--2017-05-23 22:09:55--  http://localhost/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2017-05-23 22:09:55 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

How can I know which service is firing up this docker process ?

I looked in the `/etc/init.d/` directory:

```
$ l /etc/init.d/
alsa-utils*  checkroot-bootclean.sh*  halt*   mattermostd*    nginxd*        rc*      single*    uuidd*
anacron*   checkroot.sh*      hostname.sh*  mountall-bootclean.sh*  ntp*         rc.local*    skeleton     whoopsie*
apachedsd*   console-setup*     httpd*  mountall.sh*    ondemand*      rcS*     ssh*     x11-common*
apparmor*  cron*        hwclock.sh* mountdevsubfs.sh* openvpn*       README     tomcatd*
apport*    cups*        irqbalance* mountkernfs.sh*   php-fpm*       reboot*      udev*
avahi-daemon*  cups-browsed*      keyboardd*  mountnfs-bootclean.sh*  plymouth*      redis*     ufw*
bluetooth*   dbus*        killprocs*  mountnfs.sh*    plymouth-log*  resolvconf*  umountfs*
bootmisc.sh*   docker*      kmod*   mysqld*     postfix*       rsync*     umountnfs.sh*
cgroupfs-mount*  dropboxd*      lightdm*  networking*   pppd-dns*      rsyslog*     umountroot*
checkfs.sh*  grub-common*     mariadbd* network-manager*  procps*        sendsigs*    urandom*
```

The `/etc/init.d/docker` is mine and removing it from the directory, a reboot still comes up with a running docker process.

I removed the `/etc/init.d/docker` file, rebooted, and there is a docker process:

```
$ ps -ef | grep docker
root      1560     1  5 22:15 ?        00:00:06 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
root      1645  1560  0 22:15 ?        00:00:00 docker-containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd --shim docker-containerd-shim --runtime docker-runc
root      4644  1645  0 22:15 ?        00:00:00 docker-containerd-shim 069db46cca05d43c35f05ff50aaa836507cbf69e4e3d9443b6b859d0edb5b076 /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/069db46cca05d43c35f05ff50aaa836507cbf69e4e3d9443b6b859d0edb5b076 docker-runc
stephane  5520  1741  0 22:17 pts/0    00:00:00 grep docker
```

So I looked up for anything docker in all these files, but found nothing named docker:

```
$ cd /etc/init.d/
[stephane@stephane-ThinkPad-X301 init.d]
$ grep.sh docker
[stephane@stephane-ThinkPad-X301 init.d]
```

This docker process is there every time I start my laptop, even when off line.

What starts this docker process ?

Comment: What's the result of running `systemctl` in terminal?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule There is quite a large output. Anything specific in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker is being started by systemd in your environment. You can disable the entire engine by running:

```
sudo systemctl disable docker
sudo systemctl stop docker
```

You can also stop only the container that is running (the shim and Jenkins application):

```
sudo docker ps # lists the running containers along with their container id
sudo docker update --restart=no $container_id
sudo docker stop $container_id
```

If you know that you do not need this container and want to permanently delete it, you can run this instead of the above two last commands:

```
sudo docker rm -f $container_id
```

The `-f` switch also stops the container if it's currently running.

---

Edit: from your comment, your container is running under swarm mode which is redeploying it. To stop that first find the stack or service that is running it.

```
sudo docker stack ls
sudo docker service ls
```

If you see a stack listed, you can remove that with:

```
sudo docker stack rm $stack_name
```

If there are no stacks listed, or they don't apply to this container, you can delete the service with:

```
sudo docker service rm $service_name
```

Comment: I tried the `--restart=no` and the `rm -f` and the `stop` docker commands but the container is always recreated under a new random name like `jenkins-master.1.j5btxg6hbznn07smp2hczb551`. There seems to be a process that spawns a new container every time the one of the `jenkins:latest` image is stopped and removed.

Comment: @Stephane I've updated my answer to cover swarm mode which makes containers with names like that.

Comment: Removing the swarm mode service solve it: `$ docker service rm jenkins-master`.

Answer (score 3):

Lubuntu 16.04 comes with systemd by [default](http://lubuntu.me/xenial-released/). At some point you must have started up a jenkins instance in docker - it's hard to tell exactly what *started* the process initially. However, `systemd` would be what is currently causing it to start. In order to stop it from running, run the following commands:

`systemctl status docker`   <- Find out of `systemctl` thinks docker is running.

It'll likely show something like this:

`● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-05-21 22:59:46 EDT; 1 day 17h ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 1314 (dockerd-current)
    Tasks: 14 (limit: 8192)
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─1314 /usr/bin/dockerd-current --add-runtime oci=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current --default-runtime=oci --containerd /run/containerd.sock --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd --userland-proxy-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-proxy-current --selinux-enabled --log-driver=journald`

To stop it, run `systemctl stop docker` and then `systemctl disable docker`. As a last resort if this doesn't work, you can run `systemctl mask docker`.